# Titanium appcelerator search does not work with SearchBar

Tags: listview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, searchbar

I have this code:

```js
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar();

var myTemplate = {
       properties: {
                accessoryType: Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_DISCLOSURE,
            },
        childTemplates: [
            {                            
                type: 'Ti.UI.Label',    
                bindId: 'destinazione',  
                properties: {
                    left: '24%'
                }
            },
        ]
    };

    var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
        templates: { 'template': myTemplate },
        defaultItemTemplate: 'template',
        searchView: search
    });
```

After recovering the data to be entered with onload

```js
xhrPart.onload = function() {
        partenzeJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (i in partenzeJSON){    
            var flightSection = Ti.UI.createListSection();
            var flightDataSet = [];

            flightDataSet = [{ 
                destinazione: {text: partenzeJSON[i].destinazione, searchableText: partenzeJSON[i].destinazione}, 
            }];
            flightSection.setItems(flightDataSet);
            sections.push(flightSection);   
        }
        listViewPartenze.setSections(sections);
    };
```

because research does not work?
does not look for the data input in the listview

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchableText` has to go into the properties of the object and not into the `label`

It should look like this:

```
flightDataSet = [{ 
  destinazione: {text: partenzeJSON[i].destinazione},
  properties: {searchableText: partenzeJSON[i].destinazione}
}];
```